# VBA another for-loop question

Tags: vba, foreach

I know there are a ton of questions about constructing looped codes in vBA already but hopefully this will be a quick answer, i wasn't able to find a page addressing this issue.

My goal is to check the values from one range with values in another range, and if is a match it will perform a function and display results at the end.  However, if the corresponding value in the range is "N/A" I want the results to display immediately and move onto the next checked value.  Right now I am obtaining a 'no for loop' error for my code and i understand why.  But I don't know how to fix this problem.  Can anyone help?

```
Sub solubility()

Dim coeff As Range, groups As Range
Dim anion As Range
Dim a As Range
Dim nextrow As Long
Dim j As Range

Worksheets("properties").Select
Range("P7:P2000").Select
Selection.ClearContents

'solubility groups range
groups = Worksheets("Solubility").Range("A2:A33")
'group coefficients range
coeff = Worksheets("Solubility").Range("B2:B33")

anion = Worksheets("properties").Range("AB7:AB887")

For Each a In anion
   For Each j In groups
        If UCase(a.Value) = UCase(groups(j).Value) Then
             If groups(j).Value = "" Or "N/A" Then
                Worksheets("properties").Range("P" & a.Row).Value = "N/A"
                Next a
             Else
                anvalue = coeff(j).Value * Range("AC" & a.Row).Value
             End If
        End If
        If UCase(Range("AD" & a.Row).Value) = UCase(groups(j).Value) Then
            cavalue = coeff(j).Value * Worksheets("properties").Range("AE" & a.Row).Value
        If UCase(Range("AF" & a.Row).Value) = UCase(groups(j).Value) Then
            cb1value = coeff(j).Value * Worksheets("properties").Range("AG" & a.Row).Value
        End If
        If UCase(Range("AH" & a.Row).Value) = UCase(groups(j).Value) Then
            cb2value = coeff(j).Value * Worksheets("properties").Range("AI" & a.Row).Value
        End If
   Next j
        If UCase(Range("AD" & a.Row).Value) = UCase("[MIm]") Then
            cavalue = Range("AE" & a.Row) * Worksheets("solubility").Range("B2").Value + Range("AE" & a.Row) * Worksheets("solubility").Range("B7").Value
        End If
    nextrow = Worksheets("properties").Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Worksheets("properties").Range("P" & nextrow).Value = _
        anvalue + cavalue + cb1value + cb2value + Worksheets("solubility").Range("b34").Value
Next a
End Sub
```

I have the line 'Next a' twice, and excel doesnt like this, but I want to automatically jump to the next checked value without performing the remaining function if I get the "N/A" value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this will rile the feathers of some of my purist brethren, but I would actually suggest a judicious use of `GoTo` in your case:

```
    For Each a In anion
       For Each j In groups
            If UCase(a.Value) = UCase(groups(j).Value) Then
                 If groups(j).Value = "" Or "N/A" Then
                    Worksheets("properties").Range("P" & a.Row).Value = "N/A"
                    GoTo NextA
                    ....
                 End If
            End If
            ....
       Next j
       ....
NextA:
    Next a
```

Overuse of `GoTo` will quickly turn your code into spaghetti, but in this case I think it is actually the most readable option you have.

Comment: Thanks! that helped my answer, I also forgot an end if somewhere which was originally throwing off my errors as well.

Comment: I would propose "Exit For" as being preferable to GoTo (though I don't consider myself a purist...)

Comment: Exit For only gets him out of the inner "j" loop.  There are three additional lines that he would still need to skip before he gets to the `Next a` line.  He could set some sort of flag and wrap those three lines in an If statement, but I think that is less readable than a GoTo here.

Comment: @mwolfe02 - yes, I missed that it needed to jump out of nested loops

Comment: what is so bad about GoTO commands?  Does VBA get confused if i put too many of those in?

Comment: VBA does not get confused.  The danger is that it can make code harder to understand.  Refer to the following discussions for more info: [What's the most acceptable use of 'goto' you've ever seen?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6755/whats-the-most-acceptable-use-of-goto-youve-ever-seen) and [Is it ever worthwhile using goto?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/566/is-it-ever-worthwhile-using-goto)

Answer (score 0):

You must define a reference to an object using SET:

```
SET groups = Worksheets("Solubility").Range("A2:A33")
```

(Same for all ranges)

Comment: Thanks for the tip iDevlop, always nice to some feedback about my code.  Cuts down on debugging later on!